# excel cell position in java

Tags: java, excel

In one requirement I need to parse a excel file where data can be in cell as well as in row-span and column-span. after parsing I need to create a xml file. witch further needs to be pass as an argument to pre-existing algorithm, which extracts data depending upon some position logic. I need a parser which can extract data with following meta data--
1-cell position (row, column)
2-row-span and column-span
3-height and width of both

if possible please help.I am using java.  Thanks.

Comment: if you need one, write one. try with `apache-poi` to read excel file

Comment: this should help you: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents

Answer (score 0):

You can try **jxl** [JExcelApi] library for that.
There is a [getMergedCells](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Sheet.html#getMergedCells()) method which return `Range` reference containing information about merged cell.