# I need to insert the values in excel. How can I do it?

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to insert the values generated by the java in the output console into the excel sheet in 32*10 format. How can it be done.

the code is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;



// Java program to print all permutations of a
// given string.
// ****************************************
//modify is the number of operators
//brck_no is the paranthesis combination
// please change these two values while experimenting

public class testmcdc
{   static  int modify=5;
   static int brck_no=1;
static int[] val = new int[1000]    ;            //array declaration as global

static int mcdctc=-1;
static int[][] value = new int[1000][1000];
 static int colval=-1;



public static void main(String[] args)
{
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Java Books");
  //  System.out.println("An incremented value");

    for(int i=modify;i<=modify;i++) {
        String p="";
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++) {
            for(int m=0;m<j;m++) {
                p=p+"&";
                    }
            for(int m=0;m<i-j;m++) {
                p=p+"|";
                    }
             printAllPermutations(p);
            p="";
        //System.out.print("**"+j);

        }
    }
   // System.out.println(); 
  //  System.out.println("***********************;***********"); 
   // System.out.println(); 
    for(int h1=0;h1<Math.pow(2,modify);h1++){
        for(int h2=0;h2<Math.pow(2,modify+1);h2++){

        //    System.out.print(value[h1][h2]+" ");
        }
     //  System.out.println(); 
    }

}

public int[] check(int val[]) {   //ACCEPTING 1D VALUE FROM PRINT FUNC

int N=3;
// test10 t=new test10();              //TRYING TO CONVERT 1 D TO 2 D ARRAY

for(int r=0;r<1;r++){  
    for(int ij=0;ij<Math.pow(2,N);ij++)
    {
     //   System.out.print(" "+val[ij]);
    }     
}

return val;

}



static int[] print(char[] temp) { //GENERATING INT VALUES

    String a="";
//  System.out.println();
  for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)

  { //System.out.print(temp[i]);
        a=a+temp[i];

  }
  //-----------------negation changes----------------
  int ray=(int)Math.pow(2,modify+1);
  int neg_var_mat[][]=new int[ray][modify+2];
  int neg_col_val=0;
  int min_mcdc_tc[]=new int[(temp.length+1)*2];
  int keep_tc=0;
  mcdctc++;
  String mh=a.replace('|', '0');
  mh=mh.replace('&', '1');
 // System.out.println("repl   "+mh);
  for(int mh2=0;mh2<=mh.length();mh2++) {
      String t_val=mh.substring(0, mh2)+"1"+mh.substring(mh2, mh.length());
     // System.out.println(t_val);
      //System.out.println("Output: "+Integer.parseInt(t_val,2));
      int t_val_int=Integer.parseInt(t_val,2);
      min_mcdc_tc[keep_tc++]=t_val_int;
      String f_val=mh.substring(0, mh2)+"0"+mh.substring(mh2, mh.length());
     // System.out.println(f_val);
     // System.out.println("Output: "+Integer.parseInt(f_val,2));
      int f_val_int=Integer.parseInt(f_val,2);
      min_mcdc_tc[keep_tc++]=f_val_int;
  }
  for(int i=0;i<(temp.length+1)*2;i++){
     // System.out.println(min_mcdc_tc[i]);
  }
  int n = min_mcdc_tc.length;
      printDistinct(min_mcdc_tc, n);

        //System.out.println("*");
        System.out.println();
     colval++;
  //System.out.print(" "+"opr:"+temp.length+"   ");
  final int N = temp.length+1;  

  /*===================INT GENERATION START========================*/
  for (int i = 0; i < (1 << N); i++) {                          
    // System.out.println(zeroPad(Integer.toBinaryString(i), N));
     String b=zeroPad(Integer.toBinaryString(i), N)+"";
    // System.out.println("a:  "+a+"  b:"+b);
     char[] arrayA = b.toCharArray();
     char[] arrayB = a.toCharArray();
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

     int ii = 0;
     while( ii < arrayA.length && ii < arrayB.length){
         sb.append(arrayA[ii]).append(arrayB[ii]);
         ++ii;
     }

     for(int j = ii; j < arrayA.length; ++j){
         sb.append(arrayA[j]);
     }

     for(int j = ii; j < arrayB.length; ++j){
         sb.append(arrayB[j]);
     }

     ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine se = sem.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String myExpression = sb.toString();
//  System.out.println("my exp "+myExpression);
    List outcomes = findAllOutcomes(myExpression);

    val[i]=(int)outcomes.get(brck_no);
    value[colval][i]=val[i];
    neg_var_mat[neg_col_val][0]=val[i];
    for(int i2=0,k=1;i2<myExpression.length();i2=i2+2)
    {  if(myExpression.charAt(i2)=='1') {
        String newmut=myExpression.substring(0, i2)+"0"+myExpression.substring(i2+1, myExpression.length());
        List outcomes1 = findAllOutcomes(newmut);
        int valdata=(int)outcomes1.get(brck_no);
        neg_var_mat[neg_col_val][k++]=valdata;
    //  System.out.println("my mutatant "+newmut+ "   "+ valdata);
    }
    else {
        String newmut=myExpression.substring(0, i2)+"1"+myExpression.substring(i2+1, myExpression.length());
        List outcomes1 = findAllOutcomes(newmut);
        int valdata=(int)outcomes1.get(brck_no);
        neg_var_mat[neg_col_val][k++]=valdata;

    //  System.out.println("my mutatant "+newmut+ "   "+ valdata);

    }


    }
    neg_col_val++;
    //String brack="((()))";





    /*$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ */

  //    System.out.println("   "+val[i]);
    //NEED TO HAVE THESE VALUES IN THE 1-D ARRAY
     // System.out.print(val[i]);


  }  
  /*===================GENERATION OF INT VALUES STOPS OR BECOMES LOOP==================*/

 //PASS VALUES TO CHECK FUNCTION ABOVE

 //testmcdc aa=new testmcdc();
 //aa.check(val);
  //int neg_var_mat[][]=new int[ray][modify+2];
  for(int p1=0;p1<ray;p1++) {
      for(int p2=0;p2<modify+2;p2++) {
         // System.out.print(neg_var_mat[p1][p2]+"   ");
      }
     // System.out.println("");
  }
 int pict[]=new int[]{8,55,20,3,57,46};
  int pict3w[]=new int[]{2,49,31,39,44,24,43,13,1,50,62,20};
  int mcdc[][]={
      { 32 , 0 , 16 , 8 , 4 , 2 , 1 }, 

{48 , 16 , 32 , 40 , 36 , 34 , 33 }, 

{40 , 8 , 24 , 16 , 20 , 18 , 17 }, 

{36 , 4 , 20 , 12 , 8 , 10 , 9 }, 

{34 , 2 , 18 , 10 , 6 , 4 , 5 }, 

{33 , 1 , 17 , 9 , 5 , 3 , 2 }, 

{56 , 24 , 40 , 48 , 52 , 50 , 49 }, 

{52 , 20 , 36 , 44 , 40 , 42 , 41 }, 

{50 , 18 , 34 , 42 , 38 , 36 , 37 }, 

{49 , 17 , 33 , 41 , 37 , 35 , 34 }, 

{44 , 12 , 28 , 20 , 24 , 26 , 25 }, 

{42 , 10 , 26 , 18 , 22 , 20 , 21 }, 

{41 , 9 , 25 , 17 , 21 , 19 , 18 }, 

{38 , 6 , 22 , 14 , 10 , 12 , 13 }, 

{37 , 5 , 21 , 13 , 9 , 11 , 10 }, 

{35 , 3 , 19 , 11 , 7 , 5 , 6 }, 

{60 , 28 , 44 , 52 , 56 , 58 , 57 }, 

{58 , 26 , 42 , 50 , 54 , 52 , 53 }, 

{57 , 25 , 41 , 49 , 53 , 51 , 50 }, 

{54 , 22 , 38 , 46 , 42 , 44 , 45 }, 

{53 , 21 , 37 , 45 , 41 , 43 , 42 }, 

{51 , 19 , 35 , 43 , 39 , 37 , 38 }, 

{46 , 14 , 30 , 22 , 26 , 28 , 29 }, 

{45 , 13 , 29 , 21 , 25 , 27 , 26 }, 

{43 , 11 , 27 , 19 , 23 , 21 , 22 }, 

{39 , 7 , 23 , 15 , 11 , 13 , 14 }, 

{62 , 30 , 46 , 54 , 58 , 60 , 61 }, 

{61 , 29 , 45 , 53 , 57 , 59 , 58 }, 

{59 , 27 , 43 , 51 , 55 , 53 , 54 }, 

{55 , 23 , 39 , 47 , 43 , 45 , 46 }, 

{47 , 15 , 31 , 23 , 27 , 29 , 30 }, 

{63 , 31 , 47 , 55 , 59 , 61 , 62 }, 

  };
  int equal2=0;
  int equal3=0;
  int pct=0; 
  int pct3w=0;// pict
  int mcd2=0;
  int mcd3=0;// mcdc
  int ft_ov=0;
  int mcd_ov=0;
  int pct_ov=0;
  int pct3w_ov=0;


    for(int h2=1;h2<=(1+modify);h2++){
         int count_faults=0;
          int pict_det=0;
          int pict3w_det=0;
          int mcdc_det=0;
    //    System.out.println("Column "+(h2+1));

        for(int h3=0;h3<Math.pow(2,modify+1);h3++){
           // System.out.println("=================================");
           // System.out.println("row "+(h2+1)+" mutatnt "+(h3+1));
            if(neg_var_mat[h3][0]!=neg_var_mat[h3][h2]) {

            //    System.out.print("galti  "+(h3));
                for (int hh=0;hh<pict.length;hh++) {
                    if(pict[hh]==h3) {pict_det++;}
                }
                for (int hh=0;hh<pict3w.length;hh++) {
                    if(pict3w[hh]==h3) {pict3w_det++;}
                }
                for (int hh=0;hh<mcdc[h2].length;hh++) {
                    if(mcdc[mcdctc][hh]==h3) {mcdc_det++;}
                }
                  count_faults++;               
            }

        }

    //    System.out.println("\n");
        ft_ov+=count_faults;
        mcd_ov+=mcdc_det;
        pct_ov+=pict_det;
        pct3w_ov+=pict3w_det;
  //      System.out.println(" Total Faults "+count_faults);

    //    System.out.println(" Faults Detected by Pict "+pict_det);
    //    System.out.println(" Faults Detected by MCDC "+mcdc_det);
    //    System.out.println(" Faults Detected by Pict-3way "+pict3w_det);
        if (pict_det==mcdc_det){equal2++;}
        else if(pict_det>mcdc_det){pct++;}
        else {mcd2++;}

        if (pict3w_det==mcdc_det){equal3++;}
        else if(pict3w_det>mcdc_det){pct3w++;}
        else {mcd3++;}
    }

  // System.out.println("**************Comparison Between 2-way and MC/DC Testing***********************"); 
  // System.out.println("=########################################################################################################################======");

   System.out.print(" "+equal2); 
      System.out.print(" "+mcd2);
       System.out.print(" "+pct);






   System.out.print(" "+equal3); 

      System.out.print(" "+mcd3);

      System.out.print(" "+pct3w);
   System.out.print(" "+ft_ov); 
      System.out.print(" "+pct_ov);
      System.out.print(" "+mcd_ov);
      System.out.println(" "+pct3w_ov);


 return val;

}


/*NO CHANGE NEEDED FROM HERE::THESE FUNC HELPS IN GENERATING EXPRESSION AND EVALUATE THE EXPRESSION............*/
static int factorial(int n) {
  int f = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    f = f * i;
  return f;
}

static int calculateTotal(char[] temp, int n) {
  int f = factorial(n);

  // Building HashMap to store frequencies of 
  // all characters.
  HashMap<Character, Integer> hm = 
                   new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
  for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    if (hm.containsKey(temp[i]))
      hm.put(temp[i], hm.get(temp[i]) + 1);

    else
      hm.put(temp[i], 1);
  }

  // Traversing hashmap and finding duplicate elements.
  for (Map.Entry e : hm.entrySet()) {
    Integer x = (Integer)e.getValue();
    if (x > 1) {
      int temp5 = factorial(x);
      f = f / temp5;
    }
  }
  return f;
}

static void nextPermutation(char[] temp) {

  // Start traversing from the end and
  // find position 'i-1' of the first character 
  // which is greater than its  successor. 
  int i;
  for (i = temp.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    if (temp[i] > temp[i - 1])
      break;

  // Finding smallest character after 'i-1' and
  // greater than temp[i-1]
  int min = i;
  int j, x = temp[i - 1];
  for (j = i + 1; j < temp.length; j++)
    if ((temp[j] < temp[min]) && (temp[j] > x))
      min = j;

  // Swapping the above found characters.
  char temp_to_swap;
  temp_to_swap = temp[i - 1];
  temp[i - 1] = temp[min];
  temp[min] = temp_to_swap;

  // Sort all digits from position next to 'i-1'
  // to end of the string.
  Arrays.sort(temp, i, temp.length);

  // Print the String
  print(temp);
}

static void printAllPermutations(String s) {

  // Sorting String
  char temp[] = s.toCharArray();
  Arrays.sort(temp);

  // Print first permutation
  print(temp);
  //System.out.print("** ");


  // Finding the total permutations
  int total = calculateTotal(temp, temp.length);
  for (int i = 1; i < total; i++)
    {nextPermutation(temp);
    }
}
static String zero(int L) {                                      
      return (L <= 0 ? "" : String.format("%0" + L + "d", 0));      
   }                                                               
static String zeroPad(String s, int L) {                        
      return zero(L - s.length()) + s;                              
   } 



static List<Integer> findAllOutcomes(String s)
{
    List<Integer> currentResults = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean noOp = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {

        if(s.charAt(i) == '&' || s.charAt(i) == '|')
        {
            noOp = false;

            List<Integer> left = findAllOutcomes(s.substring(0, i));
            List<Integer> right = findAllOutcomes(s.substring(i + 1));
            //System.out.print(" L "+left);
            //System.out.print(" R "+right);

            for(Integer l : left){
                for(Integer r : right){
                    currentResults.add(evaluate(s.charAt(i), l, r));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(noOp){
        currentResults.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
    }
    return currentResults;
}

static int evaluate(char operator, int lhs, int rhs)
{
    if(operator == '|')
    {
        return lhs | rhs;
    }
    else{
        return lhs & rhs;
    }

}
static void printDistinct(int arr[], int n)
{
    // Pick all elements one by one
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // Check if the picked element 
        // is already printed
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        if (arr[i] == arr[j])
            break;

        // If not printed earlier, 
        // then print it
        if (i == j){ /* System.out.print( arr[i] + " ");*/}

    }
}

}
```

The output is:

0 6 0 0 6 0 12 1 12 2

1 5 0 0 5 1 72 6 16 12

1 5 0 0 4 2 72 7 16 14

1 5 0 1 4 1 56 9 16 10

0 6 0 0 6 0 28 3 16 7

0 6 0 1 5 0 40 4 16 10

0 6 0 0 4 2 68 6 18 14

0 6 0 1 4 1 84 6 18 16

0 5 1 0 5 1 80 6 18 13

0 5 1 0 5 1 84 7 18 14

0 5 1 0 5 1 84 6 18 17

1 5 0 1 4 1 80 9 18 16

1 5 0 0 5 1 84 8 18 15

0 6 0 2 4 0 64 7 18 11

0 6 0 2 4 0 68 7 18 11

0 6 0 0 6 0 48 6 18 8

0 6 0 0 6 0 48 6 18 8

0 6 0 1 4 1 68 5 18 13

0 6 0 2 4 0 64 7 18 13

1 5 0 1 4 1 84 8 18 17

0 6 0 0 4 2 80 7 18 18

0 5 1 0 5 1 84 6 18 17

1 5 0 0 5 1 84 5 18 14

0 5 1 0 5 1 80 6 18 15

0 6 0 1 4 1 84 6 18 14

0 6 0 1 4 1 68 6 18 12

0 6 0 0 6 0 40 6 16 8

0 6 0 0 6 0 28 3 16 3

1 5 0 1 4 1 56 9 16 10

1 5 0 0 4 2 72 7 16 14

1 5 0 0 5 1 72 6 16 16

0 6 0 0 6 0 12 1 12 2

how can we do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999868/excel-cell-position-in-java/44000654#44000654 this answer can help you.This is not what you require but this library will help full to you.

Comment: You can use Apache POI to complete this task. Please refer https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/ for example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works using the Apache POI library:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

// Java program to print all permutations of a given string. 
// **************************************** 
// modify is the number of operators 
// brck_no is the paranthesis combination 
// please change these two values while experimenting 
public class testmcdc {

   static int modify = 5;
   static int brck_no = 1;
   static int[] val = new int[1000];
   //  array declaration as global 
   static int mcdctc = -1;
   static int[][] value = new int[1000][1000];
   static int colval = -1;

   static int rowNum = 0;
   static XSSFSheet sheet;
   static String excelFile = "output.xlsx";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // create excel workbook
      XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
      sheet = workbook.createSheet("Java Books");
      // add header to current sheet 
      List<String> header = Arrays.asList("equal2", "mcd2", "pct", "equal3", "mcd3", "pct3w", "ft_ov", "pct_ov", "mcd_ov", "pct3w_ov");
      addRow(sheet, rowNum++, header);

      for (int i = modify; i <= modify; i++) {
         String p = "";
         for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            for (int m = 0; m < j; m++) {
               p = p + "&";
            }
            for (int m = 0; m < i - j; m++) {
               p = p + "|";
            }
            printAllPermutations(p);
            p = "";
         }
      }
      //   write workbook to file 
      try {
         FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(excelFile);
         workbook.write(outputStream);
         workbook.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   static int[] print(char[] temp) {
      //  GENERATING INT VALUES 
      String a = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
         a = a + temp[i];
      }
      //  -----------------negation changes---------------- 
      int ray = (int) Math.pow(2, modify + 1);
      int neg_var_mat[][] = new int[ray][modify + 2];
      int neg_col_val = 0;
      int min_mcdc_tc[] = new int[(temp.length + 1) * 2];
      int keep_tc = 0;
      mcdctc++;
      String mh = a.replace('|', '0');
      mh = mh.replace('&', '1');
      for (int mh2 = 0; mh2 <= mh.length(); mh2++) {
         String t_val = mh.substring(0, mh2) + "1" + mh.substring(mh2, mh.length());
         int t_val_int = Integer.parseInt(t_val, 2);
         min_mcdc_tc[keep_tc++] = t_val_int;
         String f_val = mh.substring(0, mh2) + "0" + mh.substring(mh2, mh.length());
         int f_val_int = Integer.parseInt(f_val, 2);
         min_mcdc_tc[keep_tc++] = f_val_int;
      }
      int n = min_mcdc_tc.length;
      printDistinct(min_mcdc_tc, n);
      System.out.println();
      colval++;
      final int N = temp.length + 1;
      // ===================INT GENERATION START========================
      for (int i = 0; i < (1 << N); i++) {
         String b = zeroPad(Integer.toBinaryString(i), N) + "";
         char[] arrayA = b.toCharArray();
         char[] arrayB = a.toCharArray();
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         int ii = 0;
         while (ii < arrayA.length && ii < arrayB.length) {
            sb.append(arrayA[ii]).append(arrayB[ii]);
            ++ii;
         }
         for (int j = ii; j < arrayA.length; ++j) {
            sb.append(arrayA[j]);
         }
         for (int j = ii; j < arrayB.length; ++j) {
            sb.append(arrayB[j]);
         }
         ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
         ScriptEngine se = sem.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
         String myExpression = sb.toString();
         List outcomes = findAllOutcomes(myExpression);
         val[i] = (int) outcomes.get(brck_no);
         value[colval][i] = val[i];
         neg_var_mat[neg_col_val][0] = val[i];
         for (int i2 = 0, k = 1; i2 < myExpression.length(); i2 = i2 + 2) {
            if (myExpression.charAt(i2) == '1') {
               String newmut = myExpression.substring(0, i2) + "0" + myExpression.substring(i2 + 1, myExpression.length());
               List outcomes1 = findAllOutcomes(newmut);
               int valdata = (int) outcomes1.get(brck_no);
               neg_var_mat[neg_col_val][k++] = valdata;
            } else {
               String newmut = myExpression.substring(0, i2) + "1" + myExpression.substring(i2 + 1, myExpression.length());
               List outcomes1 = findAllOutcomes(newmut);
               int valdata = (int) outcomes1.get(brck_no);
               neg_var_mat[neg_col_val][k++] = valdata;
            }
         }
         neg_col_val++;
         // $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ 
         //  NEED TO HAVE THESE VALUES IN THE 1-D ARRAY 
      }
      // ===================GENERATION OF INT VALUES STOPS OR BECOMES LOOP==================
      //  PASS VALUES TO CHECK FUNCTION ABOVE 
      //  testmcdc aa=new testmcdc(); 
      //  aa.check(val); 
      //  int neg_var_mat[][]=new int[ray][modify+2]; 
      int pict[] = new int[]{8, 55, 20, 3, 57, 46};
      int pict3w[] = new int[]{2, 49, 31, 39, 44, 24, 43, 13, 1, 50, 62, 20};
      int mcdc[][] = {{32, 0, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1}, {48, 16, 32, 40, 36, 34, 33}, {40, 8, 24, 16, 20, 18, 17}, {36, 4, 20, 12, 8, 10, 9}, {34, 2, 18, 10, 6, 4, 5}, {33, 1, 17, 9, 5, 3, 2}, {56, 24, 40, 48, 52, 50, 49}, {52, 20, 36, 44, 40, 42, 41}, {50, 18, 34, 42, 38, 36, 37}, {49, 17, 33, 41, 37, 35, 34}, {44, 12, 28, 20, 24, 26, 25}, {42, 10, 26, 18, 22, 20, 21}, {41, 9, 25, 17, 21, 19, 18}, {38, 6, 22, 14, 10, 12, 13}, {37, 5, 21, 13, 9, 11, 10}, {35, 3, 19, 11, 7, 5, 6}, {60, 28, 44, 52, 56, 58, 57}, {58, 26, 42, 50, 54, 52, 53}, {57, 25, 41, 49, 53, 51, 50}, {54, 22, 38, 46, 42, 44, 45}, {53, 21, 37, 45, 41, 43, 42}, {51, 19, 35, 43, 39, 37, 38}, {46, 14, 30, 22, 26, 28, 29}, {45, 13, 29, 21, 25, 27, 26}, {43, 11, 27, 19, 23, 21, 22}, {39, 7, 23, 15, 11, 13, 14}, {62, 30, 46, 54, 58, 60, 61}, {61, 29, 45, 53, 57, 59, 58}, {59, 27, 43, 51, 55, 53, 54}, {55, 23, 39, 47, 43, 45, 46}, {47, 15, 31, 23, 27, 29, 30}, {63, 31, 47, 55, 59, 61, 62},};
      int equal2 = 0;
      int equal3 = 0;
      int pct = 0;
      int pct3w = 0;//   pict 
      int mcd2 = 0;
      int mcd3 = 0;//   mcdc 
      int ft_ov = 0;
      int mcd_ov = 0;
      int pct_ov = 0;
      int pct3w_ov = 0;
      for (int h2 = 1; h2 <= (1 + modify); h2++) {
         int count_faults = 0;
         int pict_det = 0;
         int pict3w_det = 0;
         int mcdc_det = 0;
         for (int h3 = 0; h3 < Math.pow(2, modify + 1); h3++) {
            if (neg_var_mat[h3][0] != neg_var_mat[h3][h2]) {
               for (int hh = 0; hh < pict.length; hh++) {
                  if (pict[hh] == h3) {
                     pict_det++;
                  }
               }
               for (int hh = 0; hh < pict3w.length; hh++) {
                  if (pict3w[hh] == h3) {
                     pict3w_det++;
                  }
               }
               for (int hh = 0; hh < mcdc[h2].length; hh++) {
                  if (mcdc[mcdctc][hh] == h3) {
                     mcdc_det++;
                  }
               }
               count_faults++;
            }
         }
         ft_ov += count_faults;
         mcd_ov += mcdc_det;
         pct_ov += pict_det;
         pct3w_ov += pict3w_det;
         //      System.out.println(" Total Faults "+count_faults); 
         //      System.out.println(" Faults Detected by Pict "+pict_det); 
         //      System.out.println(" Faults Detected by MCDC "+mcdc_det); 
         //      System.out.println(" Faults Detected by Pict-3way "+pict3w_det); 
         if (pict_det == mcdc_det) {
            equal2++;
         } else if (pict_det > mcdc_det) {
            pct++;
         } else {
            mcd2++;
         }
         if (pict3w_det == mcdc_det) {
            equal3++;
         } else if (pict3w_det > mcdc_det) {
            pct3w++;
         } else {
            mcd3++;
         }
      }
      //   System.out.println("**************Comparison Between 2-way and MC/DC Testing***********************");  
      //   System.out.println("=########################################################################################################################======"); 
      System.out.print(" " + equal2);
      System.out.print(" " + mcd2);
      System.out.print(" " + pct);
      System.out.print(" " + equal3);
      System.out.print(" " + mcd3);
      System.out.print(" " + pct3w);
      System.out.print(" " + ft_ov);
      System.out.print(" " + pct_ov);
      System.out.print(" " + mcd_ov);
      System.out.println(" " + pct3w_ov);

      //  create new row with computed values:
      List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(equal2, mcd2, pct, equal3, mcd3, pct3w, ft_ov, pct_ov, mcd_ov, pct3w_ov);
      addRow(sheet, rowNum++, data);

      return val;
   }

   private static void addRow(XSSFSheet sheet, int rowNr, List data) {
      System.out.printf("sheet: adding row #%d%n", rowNr);
      Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNr);
      data.forEach(rowElem -> {
         Cell cell = row.createCell(data.indexOf(rowElem));
         if (rowElem instanceof String) {
            cell.setCellValue((String) rowElem);
         } else if (rowElem instanceof Integer) {
            cell.setCellValue((Integer) rowElem);
         }
      });
   }

   // NO CHANGE NEEDED FROM HERE::THESE FUNC HELPS IN GENERATING EXPRESSION AND EVALUATE THE EXPRESSION............
   static int factorial(int n) {
      int f = 1;
      for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
         f = f * i;
      }
      return f;
   }

   static int calculateTotal(char[] temp, int n) {
      int f = factorial(n);
      //   Building HashMap to store frequencies of  
      //   all characters. 
      HashMap<Character, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
      for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
         if (hm.containsKey(temp[i])) {
            hm.put(temp[i], hm.get(temp[i]) + 1);
         } else {
            hm.put(temp[i], 1);
         }
      }
      //   Traversing hashmap and finding duplicate elements. 
      for (Map.Entry e : hm.entrySet()) {
         Integer x = (Integer) e.getValue();
         if (x > 1) {
            int temp5 = factorial(x);
            f = f / temp5;
         }
      }
      return f;
   }

   static void nextPermutation(char[] temp) {
      //   Start traversing from the end and 
      //   find position 'i-1' of the first character  
      //   which is greater than its  successor.  
      int i;
      for (i = temp.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
         if (temp[i] > temp[i - 1]) {
            break;
         }
      }
      //   Finding smallest character after 'i-1' and 
      //   greater than temp[i-1] 
      int min = i;
      int j, x = temp[i - 1];
      for (j = i + 1; j < temp.length; j++) {
         if ((temp[j] < temp[min]) && (temp[j] > x)) {
            min = j;
         }
      }
      //   Swapping the above found characters. 
      char temp_to_swap;
      temp_to_swap = temp[i - 1];
      temp[i - 1] = temp[min];
      temp[min] = temp_to_swap;
      //   Sort all digits from position next to 'i-1' 
      //   to end of the string. 
      Arrays.sort(temp, i, temp.length);
      //   Print the String 
      print(temp);
   }

   static void printAllPermutations(String s) {
      //   Sorting String 
      char temp[] = s.toCharArray();
      Arrays.sort(temp);
      //   Print first permutation 
      print(temp);
      //  System.out.print("** "); 
      //   Finding the total permutations 
      int total = calculateTotal(temp, temp.length);
      for (int i = 1; i < total; i++) {
         nextPermutation(temp);
      }
   }

   static String zero(int L) {
      return (L <= 0 ? "" : String.format("%0" + L + "d", 0));
   }

   static String zeroPad(String s, int L) {
      return zero(L - s.length()) + s;
   }

   static List<Integer> findAllOutcomes(String s) {
      List<Integer> currentResults = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      boolean noOp = true;
      for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
         if (s.charAt(i) == '&' || s.charAt(i) == '|') {
            noOp = false;
            List<Integer> left = findAllOutcomes(s.substring(0, i));
            List<Integer> right = findAllOutcomes(s.substring(i + 1));
            for (Integer l : left) {
               for (Integer r : right) {
                  currentResults.add(evaluate(s.charAt(i), l, r));
               }
            }
         }
      }
      if (noOp) {
         currentResults.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
      }
      return currentResults;
   }

   static int evaluate(char operator, int lhs, int rhs) {
      if (operator == '|') {
         return lhs | rhs;
      } else {
         return lhs & rhs;
      }
   }

   static void printDistinct(int arr[], int n) {
      //   Pick all elements one by one 
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         //   Check if the picked element  
         //   is already printed 
         int j;
         for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
               break;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not drilled down to your code, but if the question is how to write int values to CSV file, you can use the open source Open-CSV (currently the latest version is 4.2).

In the following example you can see how I wrote 2D int matrix to CSV.
Use this code as a reference and do the adaptation you need for your code.

```
static void writeAsCsv(File target, int[][] matrix) throws IOException {
    try (CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(target))) {

        for (int[] row : matrix) {

            String[] line = Arrays.stream(row)
                    .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                    .toArray(String[]::new);

            csvWriter.writeNext(line);
        }
    }
}
```